# Where is ActionFilterAttribute in asp.net mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Which package should I use to create custom action filters in asp.net 5? In previous mvc, I can create one by inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute. Now this class seems to have moved.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActionFilterAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs) is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters namespace.

All the source code for MVC [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/) so you should check there if you can't find classes where you normally find them.

Comment: Seems to be in `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters` now.